# How to update Sublime Text Editor

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I generally use sublime text for python programming and I have some questions:

(A). How to check which version of Sublime Text editor I am using. (I think it is sublime text 3 because when I click  **Help>Documentation** then it opens sublime text 3 documentation but I am not sure)

(B). Whenever I open text editor it shows a window with a message to download the latest version. When I download [sublime_text_3_build_3103_x64.tar.bz2](https://www.sublimetext.com/3) I get lots of py files inside the package so I want to know how to update this text editor.

Currently I am using Ubuntu 15.04.

Thanks.

Comment: I have Sublime 2, and to see version I just go to Help>About Sublime Text 2, and it shows me version and build.

Comment: Great answers for this question in the [Ask Ubuntu Stack Exchange](https://askubuntu.com/questions/828226/how-to-update-sublime-text-3-in-ubuntu-16-04/870802)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To check version, go to `Help --> About Sublime Text`.

**Sublime 3**: To download latest version, go to their [official site](https://www.sublimetext.com/3). You can donwload `.deb` files from there which is very easy to install. Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line). In your case it will be (assuming you downloaded the `.deb` file):

```
sudo dpkg -i sublime-text_build-3103_i386.deb
```

**Sublime 2**: Download the latest version from [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/2).

For instructions on how to install check [this link on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172698/how-do-i-install-sublime-text-2-3).

I personally don't prefer anything updating automatically, so to upgrade to latest version, I always visit the official site and grab the latest installer/package. Likewise for sublime, on prompt by sublime to download latest version I click cancel and go to official site and download for myself.

**P.S.**: your question seems off-topic on this site. You should have asked on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) instead.

**Edit:** You can download .deb from https://www.sublimetext.com/3dev

Comment: But where are the `.deb` files at the Sublime 3 official page? I haven't found any.

Comment: @prograils I am not a linux guy, but _I think_ they are providing tar balls now instead of `.deb` files. Anyway, you can get the tarballs from the official site easily. Also they give [installation guides](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html#apt) for various flavours linux there. Feel free to edit my answer that official site no longer provides `.deb` files, as a P.P.S. perhaps ;-)

Answer (score 16):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

If you want to update version, just copy and paste these commands in your terminal.

Comment: Should have been the accepted answer as it's the most convenient.

Comment: This didn't work for me. It says build 3143 is the latest version even though that is two years old.

Comment: which command from the 4 commands doesn't work ?
which linux version do you use

Answer (score 5):

Check where Sublime has been installed with the command `which subl` or `whereis -b sublime-text`. It might be in a root folder called `/snap/bin/`. ([Alternative ways](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126268/how-to-find-out-the-terminal-command-of-an-application) to find application locations)

If it is there, you have (unknowingly) installed Sublime via [Snappy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snappy_(package_manager)) (the "Ubuntu Software" application on Ubuntu 18 does that). Then you can use [`snap`](https://www.mankier.com/8/snap) to update Sublime with the terminal. Like this:

```
$ snap find sublime

Name                  Version  Publisher     Notes    Summary
subliminal-subtitles  2.0.5    nubing        -        Subtitles, faster than your thoughts
sublime-text          3207     snapcrafters  classic  A sophisticated text editor for code, markup and prose.
```

---

```
$ snap info sublime-text

name:      sublime-text
summary:   A sophisticated text editor for code, markup and prose.
publisher: Snapcrafters
contact:   https://github.com/snapcrafters/sublime-text/issues
license:   unset
description: |
  A sophisticated text editor for code, markup and prose.


  This snap is maintained by the Snapcrafters community, and is not
  necessarily endorsed or officially maintained by the upstream
  developers.
commands:
  - sublime-text.subl
snap-id:      2kOIsSRmQ7zjpIxzZDpoXaZOVejqaGOT
tracking:     stable
refresh-date: 25 days ago, at 19:58 CET
channels:
  stable:    3207 2019-04-06 (58) 70MB classic
  candidate: ↑                         
  beta:      ↑                         
  edge:      3207 2019-04-06 (58) 70MB classic
installed:   3200            (51) 70MB classic
```

---

```
$ snap refresh sublime-text
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

Answer (score 1):

Mine worked fine by following the below given steps. Source [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/828226/how-to-update-sublime-text-3-in-ubuntu-16-04?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa#870802)

> Check the path of your executable if you have one:
>
> `cat $(which subl)`
>
> *This assumes you have the executable from command line (e.g. `subl`), otherwise find a way to locate your installation (e.g. `locate
>   sublime_text`), mine was `/opt/sublime_text`.*
>
> From the [official website](https://www.sublimetext.com/3), the latest version as of editing is
>   build `3176` *(16 May 2018)*.
>
> The [64-bit tarball](https://download.sublimetext.com/sublime_text_3_build_3176_x64.tar.bz2) can be downloaded there as well as the
>   [32-bit](https://download.sublimetext.com/sublime_text_3_build_3176_x32.tar.bz2) one.
>
> Download and untar the file (one command):
>
> `curl
>   https://download.sublimetext.com/sublime_text_3_build_3176_x64.tar.bz2
>   | tar vxj`
>
> Overwrite your old installation e.g. `sudo cp -rf sublime_text_3/.
>   /opt/sublime_text`
>
> Remove the download `rm -rf sublime_text_3`
>
> And you're done!

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays they provide the way to install/update Sublime on [their website](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/linux_repositories.html#apt).

```
wget -qO - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/sublimehq-archive.gpg > /dev/null
echo "deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```